# RatingBar clear stars?

Tags: android, button, ratingbar

The are two button: ok to confirm the rate and clear for clear the rate.
I try this code, and when I press the button "clear" the first time it's ok and the clear works, but then it doesn't work and the dialog closes.
How can I change the method on click of clear button?
Thank you in advance.

```
    @Override
        protected void populateView(View rootView) throws Exception {
            super.populateView(rootView);
            voterestaurant.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final Dialog d = new Dialog(getActivity());
                    d.setTitle("Rate it!");
                    d.setCancelable(false);
                    d.setContentView(R.layout.pf_frame_rating);
                    final RatingBar RatingBar = (RatingBar) d.findViewById(R.id.MyratingBar);
                    final TextView TextRate = (TextView) d
                            .findViewById(R.id.ratetext);
                    Button ok = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.bt_confirm);
                    TextRate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


RatingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

                                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar,
                                        float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                                    int rate = (int) RatingBar.getRating();

                                    Math.ceil(rate);
                                    // TextRate.setText(String.valueOf(rate));
                                    switch (rate) {
                                    case 0:
                                        TextRate.setText(String.valueOf("Pessimo"));
                                        break;
                                    case 1:
                                        TextRate.setText(String.valueOf("Scarso"));
                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        TextRate.setText(String.valueOf("Buono"));
                                        break;

                                    case 3:
                                        TextRate.setText(String
                                                .valueOf("Molto buono"));
                                        break;

                                    case 4:
                                        TextRate.setText(String
                                                .valueOf("Eccellente!"));
                                        break;
                                    }

                                    TextRate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                }
                            });
                    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // memorizza valore rating
                            d.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    Button clear = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.bt_clear);
                    clear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            RatingBar.setRating(0F);
                            RatingBar.setFocusable(true);
                            d.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    d.show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: declare RatingBar globally. Use java naming conventions for variable name. And see if any error in logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `d.dismiss();` this line from clear button click listener and check.

Comment: and dont forget to add d.dismiss(); when your rating is confirmed. and accept the answer